# A question about quadratic form of normal variables

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, independence

Assume $X\sim N_{n}(u,\sigma ^{2}I_{n})$，$A$ and $B$ are $n×n$ symmetric matrix，moreover，$X'AX$ and $X'BX$ are independent，then how to prove $AB＝0$

Any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Let $\phi(u,v)=E\exp(tX'AX + uX'BX)$ be the mgf of the two independent quadratic forms.  Then $\phi(u,v)=\phi(u,0)\phi(0,v)$, which (among other things) implies $\det(I+tA+uB)=\det(I+tA)\det(1+uB)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a proof, which I will sketch here.  This problem is very similar to [another one posed by OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2444156/) but  possibly easier.  We know that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp(-\|x\|^2/2) \,dx$ is $(2\pi)^{n/2}$ so we know that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} \exp(-x^tQx/2)\,dx = (2\pi)^{n/2}/\sqrt{\det Q}$, at least for matrices $Q$ close to the identity matrix, and hence the moment generating function $\phi(t,u)$ of the random vector $(-x^tAx/2, -x^tBx/2)$, is given by  $$\phi(t,u)=E\exp(-t x^t A x/2 -u x^t B x/2) = \det(I+tA +uB)^{-1/2},$$ at least for sufficiently small $t$ and $u$.  If $x^tAx$ and $x^tBx$ are independent, then $\phi(t,u)=\phi(t,0)\phi(0,u)$.

This implies that $\partial^2/\partial t \partial u \log \phi(t,u)=0$
which leads to the equation $$\operatorname{tr} \left( (I+tA+uB)^{-1} A (I+tA+uB)^{-1} B\right) = 0$$ for all $(t,u)$ in some neighborhood of $(0,0)$. This in turn leads to the following identity in  $\mathbb R[[t,u]]$:
$$ S=\sum_{k,l\ge0} (-1)^{k+l}\operatorname{tr}\left( (tA+uB)^k A (tA+uB)^l B\right) = 0.$$  Easy consequences are: $\operatorname{tr}(AB^k) = \operatorname{tr}(BA^k) = 0$ for all $k\ge 1$ and (taking the  coefficient of $tu$ in $S$):$ \operatorname{tr}(ABAB+BAAB+AABB+BAAB+AABB+ABAB)=0$ from which (by making free use of the identity $\operatorname{tr}(PQ-QP)=0$) yields $$4\operatorname{tr}(AABB)+2\operatorname{tr}(ABAB)=0.\tag{*}$$

Now observe that $\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)(AB-BA)^t \ge 0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(AB+BA)(AB+BA)^t \ge 0$, from which we learn $$\operatorname{tr}(AABB)\ge\operatorname{tr}(ABAB)$$ and $$\operatorname{tr}(AABB)\ge-\operatorname{tr}(ABAB),$$ so $|\operatorname{tr}(ABAB)|\le \operatorname{tr}(AABB).$  This, together with $(*)$, implies $\operatorname{tr}(AABB)=0$ which implies $AB=0.$